# Fast load 70,000 files into array and insert into database

Tags: arrays, bash

A few days ago, I had a problem with a script dealing with a multitude of files on our EMC mass filers. Here's now my working code

```
unset xP_Array
declare -a xP_Array
...
export LOG=$HOME/BIN/somelogfile
export OUT=/path/to/device
...
echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` START -- MEM"                          >> $LOG

echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Go to work directory."                                              >> $LOG
cd ${OUT}

echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Fill the array."                                                   >> $LOG
for f in "$OUT"/*XML; do
    xP_Array+=( "${f#$OUT/}" )
done
echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Get array length."                                               >> $LOG
Plen=${#xP_Array[@]}

echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` MEM: $Plen FILES TO PROCESS."                                      >> $LOG

echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Check if zero files."                                               >> $LOG
date_fmt='%m/%d/%y %T'
if (( Plen = 0 ))
then
    printf "%($date_fmt)T: ZERO FILES\n" $(date +%s)                                            >> $LOG
fi

echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Loop."                                                             >> $LOG
for i in "${xP_Array[@]}"
do
        echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Move file to run directory."                              >> $LOG
        mv $OUT/$i RUN/
        echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` PROCESSING "$i"."                                          >> $LOG
        [[[DATABASE LOAD DONE HERE]]]
        echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` Check DB LOAD return value."                                       >> $LOG
        EXIT=`echo $?`
        case $EXIT in
                0) echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` COMPLETE."                                      >> $LOG
                mv RUN/"$i" "$ARCH"
                ;;
                *) echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` ERROR. "$i" MOVED TO RECON."                    >> $LOG
                mv RUN/"$i" "$RECON"
                ;;
        esac
done

echo "`date '+%m/%d/%y %T:'` END -- MEM"                                    >> $LOG
```

I wonder if it could work faster. I am already working with my DBA to see if the database inserts can be sped up but I wonder if the loop itself could run faster.

Btw, all the `echo` statements are redirected to a log file that I email myself when the script completes. Are they slowing the script down?

Can this script be optimized to run faster?

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to a shell script?  I'd consider trying the same script in something like Python.  You'd have to refactor the code in order to see any performance benefit though (eg use Python's datetime module instead of a subprocess calling `date`).  Also, the only *real* way to tell is to instrument the code and profile it.  It's possible that the large majority of the time is spent in the `[[[DATABASE LOAD HERE]]]` section in which case it wouldn't matter what language you were using or how much you optimized the outer shell script.

Comment: Bash is more convenient. In our shop, we all have bash as a skillset to some degree. I do think you are right with it comes to the DB load though. And also wondering if there's anything I can change in the rest of the script itself too.

Comment: it won't make it any faster, but when processing lots of files like this I like to add a progress meter, something like "23% complete (16000 of 70000 files done; estimate 0:30 remaining)"

Comment: I kinda-sorta have that...(cringe) it is a shell window that has `while true find...wc -l`...loop on the directory where the files are archived post processing. Ugly but does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in "$OUT"/*XML; do
    xP_Array+=( "${f#$OUT/}" )
done
```

could be replaced with

```
pushd "$OUT"
xP_Array=( *XML )
popd
```

but I don't think that's a big bottleneck in your script.

In your other loop, the only real overhead I see is the repeated calls to `date` and
using command substitution to assign `$?` to EXIT, which can be done directly (`EXIT=$?`). I don't think there is anything else to optimize there except the actual DB load.

If you were willing to switch from human readable dates, you could assign the current time (as a UNIX timestamp) to `SECONDS`, then just reference that variable for the log lines instead of calling `date`.

```
SECONDS=$(date +%s)
for i in "${xP_Array[@]}"
do
    echo "$SECONDS: Move file to run directory." >> $LOG
    # etc
done
```

With a new-enough bash (4.2 or later, I think), `printf` can format the UNIX timestamp as a readable time:

```
printf "%(%m/%d/%Y %T)T" $SECONDS
```

Comment: thanks for your input. The `for` loop was coded like this so files with spaces in the name can be processed without the OS word splitting them.

Comment: my version of bash (4.0.35) appears to do the right thing with spaced filenames and "arr=(*)"

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of here are the `echo "date...` statements and the `CASE` statement but the execution time for those should be really negligible. I would concentrate in tuning the SQL more than spending time fine tuning the bash script here. If you really want to do something in the script you can use the tips mentioned by @chepner already.

The other way would be, if your file formats are same, then you can merge all the files, or merge 100 files at a time as `CSV` file and then use the merged `CSV` file to load [External Tables](http://orafaq.com/node/848). You can then use the external table to load the actual table. You can start doing that by one file at a time with external table and see how much performance difference is observed.

External tables are quite handy solutions when it comes to data file (if properly formatted) since there is literally not `INSERT` and or `DELETE` efforts required, if the data file is present at the designated directory you will find data in the table else you won't (if the data file is absent, issuing a `SELECT` on the table will cause error and will generate some `log` files which can be easily taken care of).